# XML serializing node as parent class incorrectly instead of child

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I am serializing a class that is incorrectly creating the node of one of its properties.  my class structure is as follows:

Here is the top class i am serializing

```
    [DataContract]
    public class XmlReportConfiguration
    {
        [DataMember]
        [XmlArrayItem(nameof(SingleValueDescription), typeof(SingleValueDescription))]
        [XmlArrayItem(nameof(MultiValueDescription), typeof(MultiValueDescription))]
        public List<Description> Descriptions { get; set; }
    }
```

MultiValueDescription inherits from SingleValueDescription which inherits from Description.

Description has the XMlInclude tag for both the single and multi value description

My issue is when i go to serialize a Description that is of type MultiValueDescription ,  the xml node is serializing it as SingleValueDescription.

If i remove the XmlArrayItem Entry for the SingleValueDescription from the XmlReportConfiguration class, it then works as I want it to, but I cant remove that declaration for obvious reasons.

Is there some tag/declaration I'm missing here that is causing the serializer to ignore the child class for the node and use the parent class?

Here is the method when creating the serializer:

```
    public static string SerializeReportConfiguration(XmlReportConfiguration config)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlReportConfiguration));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        using (TextWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, config);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }


    public static XmlReportConfiguration DeserializeReportConfiguration(string xml)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlReportConfiguration));
        using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            XmlReportConfiguration sessionConfig = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as XmlReportConfiguration;
            return sessionConfig;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]?  It isn't even clear if you are using `DataContractSerializer` or `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: I am using XmlSerializer passing in typeof(XmlReportConfiguration).  I added my serialize method.

Comment: Can't reproduce, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/EGivyS.  Your code doesn't compile though since many types are missing.  Also, the deserialization code isn't shown.  So I had to make some guesses.

Comment: Added the deserialize part but its pretty generic so i dont know how it would help here.

Comment: Found a solution to my problem.  Posted what I used.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.  The polymorphism causes issues when serializing.  In my report config I used a list of the following new class and it solved my issues.

```
[DataContract]
public class SerializableDescription : IXmlSerializable
{
    #region Properties

    public SerializableDescription()
    {

    }

    public SerializableDescription(Description description)
    {
        Description = description;
    }

    [DataMember]
    public Description Description { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        reader.MoveToContent();
        string typeStr = reader.GetAttribute("Type");
        Type type = TypeCache.GetTypeEx(typeStr);
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(type);
        reader.ReadStartElement();
        Description = (Description)ser.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.ReadEndElement();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        Type type = Description.GetType();
        writer.WriteAttributeString("Type", type.FullName);
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(type);
        ser.Serialize(writer, Description);
    }

    #endregion
}
```